# Issues with pgRouting workshop code in PostGIS 2.11/pgRouting 2.0

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, sql, php

I'm having issues getting the pgRouting workshop code to work on PostgreSQL 9.2/PostGIS 2.11 and pgRouting 2.0 on windows.

How can I rewrite the following PHP/SQL code and make it compatible with my version:

```
<?php

  // Database connection settings
  define("PG_DB"  , "routing");
  define("PG_HOST", "localhost"); 
  define("PG_USER", "postgres");
  define("PG_PORT", "5432"); 
   define("PG_PASSWD",   "*******"); 
  define("TABLE",   "eastlegon"); 

  $counter = $pathlength = 0;

  // Retrieve start point
  $start = split(' ',$_REQUEST['startpoint']);
  $startPoint = array($start[0], $start[1]);
  
  // Retrieve end point
  $end = split(' ',$_REQUEST['finalpoint']);
  $endPoint = array($end[0], $end[1]);

  // Find the nearest edge
  $startEdge = findNearestEdge($startPoint);
  $endEdge   = findNearestEdge($endPoint);

  // FUNCTION findNearestEdge
  function findNearestEdge($lonlat) {
    
    // Connect to database
    $con = pg_connect("dbname=".PG_DB." host=".PG_HOST." user=".PG_USER." password=".PG_PASSWD);
    
    $sql = "SELECT gid, source, target, the_geom, 
             distance(the_geom, GeometryFromText(
                  'POINT(".$lonlat[0]." ".$lonlat[1].")', 4326)) AS dist 
            FROM ".TABLE."  
            WHERE the_geom && setsrid(
                  'BOX3D(".($lonlat[0]-200)." 
                         ".($lonlat[1]-200).", 
                         ".($lonlat[0]+200)." 
                         ".($lonlat[1]+200).")'::box3d, 4326) 
            ORDER BY dist LIMIT 1";

    $query = pg_query($con,$sql);  
    
    $edge['gid']      = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 0);  
    $edge['source']   = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 1);  
    $edge['target']   = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 2);  
    $edge['the_geom'] = pg_fetch_result($query, 0, 3);  

    // Close database connection
    pg_close($con);

    return $edge;
  }

  // Select the routing algorithm
  switch($_REQUEST['method']) {

    case 'SPD' : // Shortest Path Dijkstra 

      $sql = "SELECT rt.gid, AsText(rt.the_geom) AS wkt, 
                   length(rt.the_geom) AS length, ".TABLE.".id 
                FROM ".TABLE.", 
                    (SELECT gid, the_geom 
                        FROM dijkstra_sp_delta(
                            '".TABLE."',
                            ".$startEdge['source'].",
                            ".$endEdge['target'].",
                            3000)
                     ) as rt 
                WHERE ".TABLE.".gid=rt.gid;";
      break;

    case 'SPA' : // Shortest Path A* 

      $sql = "SELECT rt.gid, AsText(rt.the_geom) AS wkt, 
                     length(rt.the_geom) AS length, ".TABLE.".id 
                  FROM ".TABLE.", 
                      (SELECT gid, the_geom 
                          FROM astar_sp_delta(
                              '".TABLE."',
                              ".$startEdge['source'].",
                              ".$endEdge['target'].",
                              3000)
                       ) as rt 
                  WHERE ".TABLE.".gid=rt.gid;";  
      break;

    case 'SPS' : // Shortest Path Shooting*

      $sql = "SELECT rt.gid, AsText(rt.the_geom) AS wkt, 
                     length(rt.the_geom) AS length, ".TABLE.".id 
                  FROM ".TABLE.", 
                      (SELECT gid, the_geom 
                          FROM shootingstar_sp(
                              '".TABLE."',
                              ".$startEdge['gid'].",
                              ".$endEdge['gid'].",
                              3000, 'length', false, false)
                       ) as rt 
                  WHERE ".TABLE.".gid=rt.gid;";
      break;  

  } // close switch

  // Database connection and query
  $dbcon = pg_connect("dbname=".PG_DB." host=".PG_HOST." user=".PG_USER." password=".PG_PASSWD);

  $query = pg_query($dbcon,$sql); 
  
  // Return route as XML
  $xml  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>'."\n";
  $xml .= "<route>\n";
  
  // Add edges to XML file
  while($edge=pg_fetch_assoc($query)) {  

    $pathlength += $edge['length'];

    $xml .= "\t<edge id='".++$counter."'>\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t<id>".$edge['id']."</id>\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t<wkt>".$edge['wkt']."</wkt>\n";
    $xml .= "\t\t<length>".round(($pathlength/1000),3)."</length>\n";
    $xml .= "\t</edge>\n";
  }
  
  $xml .= "</route>\n";
        
  // Close database connection
  pg_close($dbcon);

  // Return routing result
  header('Content-type: text/xml',true);
  echo $xml;
  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The workshop code you're posting is not the current one anymore and won't work anymore with pgRouting 2.0.

If you want to use the "old" PHP function, then you need to modify it:

- Write your own plpgsql wrapper function. You can take a look at the examples in the new workshop: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html
- Change the function name, arguments, etc. according to your custom function in the PHP script.